# Empty body in POST request using OkHTTP with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

I am trying to make a POST request using OkHTTP in a Kotlin project. However, the body of the request is ending up empty.

Here is the code snippet I attempted:

```
import java.util.*
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.util.Log
import okhttp3.*//okhttp3 4.9.1
import java.io.IOException


class NetworkTask : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String {
        val name = params[0] as String
        Log.d("NetworkTask", "name: $name")
        val url = "some url"
        val requestBody = FormBody.Builder()
            .add("name", name)
            .build()

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build()

        Log.d("NetworkTask", "Request URL: ${request.url}")
        Log.d("NetworkTask", "Request method: ${request.method}")

        val client = OkHttpClient()


        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed to send POST request: ${e.message}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                println("POST request sent successfully $response")
            }
        })
        return "Request sent"
    }
}
```

I anticipated receiving a server log formatted like this:

`body:{name: "John"}`

However, the server log returned was:

`body:{}`

I'm using a translation tool, so if there are any unclear or awkward phrases, please feel free to ask for clarification. Thank you.

Comment: The `Content-Type` is compatible?

Comment: Move away from AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` solved the issue for me.